# Trocar enconding UTF8 para SQL_ASCII PgAdmin

Tags: php, codificação-de-caracteres, pgadmin

Boa tarde!

Preciso saber se é possivel eu alterar o enconding do meu banco de utf8 para SQL_ASCII, sem excluir e criar de novo o banco! O problema que está acontecendo é que meu banco está definido com Unicode UTF-8 e o Charset do site está com ISO-8859-1 dai os cararacters ficam assim "��".

Answer (score 0):

Para alterar a codificação do seu banco de dados:

1. Crie um novo banco de dados com a codificação e nome diferentes

   - ex: novo_banco (ISO-8859-1)
2. Crie um dump do seu banco de dados atual
3. Restaure o dump para o novo banco, criado no passo 1
4. Teste se seu aplicativo é executado corretamente com o novo banco de dados
5. Renomeie o banco de dados antigo

   - ex: banco_aplicacao (UTF-8) para banco_aplicacao_antigo (UTF-8)
6. Renomear o novo banco de dados com o nome do banco antigo

   - ex: novo_banco (ISO-8859-1) para banco_aplicacao (ISO-8859-1)
7. Teste o aplicativo novamente

Em caso de emergência, basta remover o banco novo e renomear o antigo

**ex:** banco_aplicacao_antigo (UTF-8) para banco_aplicacao (UTF-8)